# Get table name LINQtoSQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have combobox with the list of all the tables in my database:

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    cmbbx_tables.DataSource = db.Mapping.GetTables().Select(q=>new {q.TableName, q.RowType}).ToArray();
    cmbbx_tables.DisplayMember = "TableName";
    cmbbx_tables.ValueMember = "RowType";        
}
```

On `SelectionChangeCommitted` event I want to get the name of the selected table:

```
private void cmbbx_tables_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        String table = db.Mapping.GetTable((???)cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue).TableName;                
    }
}
```

How should I type cast cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue ?

Comment: If you're ultimately needing String type, then why are you even typecasting? Simply `cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue` will do the job, no? IOW - `String table = cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue;`

Comment: No. The combobox ValueMember is `RowType`

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. From your code `String table = ...` and your question "I want to get the name of the selected table" it seems `cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue.ToString()` will do the job.

Comment: I found solution: `(cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue as System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaType).Type`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
String name = db.Mapping.GetTable((cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue as System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaType).Type).TableName;
```

Comment: Still not sure why are you going through the hassle of calling GetTable on your context, type casting it, and then calling TableName, when its right in your lap in string form via `cmbbx_tables.SelectedValue` or `cmbbx_tables.SelectedItem.Text`